# PHP foreach null or else?

Tags: php, twitch

I'm using a basic LAMP server for my website and looking to rewrite a script I have that's linked with Twitch's API. The issue that I'm having is trying to find, for lack of a better word, the opposite of the foreach.

For example I have an array of names that are sent with a URL to the Twitch servers, and if one of the names are currently streaming "streams" will have lots of values, and if they aren't currently streaming "streams" will return null.

This works wonderful for checking people and showing they are online, but I also need it to display the ones who are offline and I can't figure out how to do that. Something like a foreachelse or something like that. This is the code I have below. Thanks.

```
<?php
$username = array("zeromi", "aerosgw", "krylen","tshirt_aion","snooky_aion","vashiro","papa456","vinley_aion","hanfkrokette","wtfast_siel","neckofthewood","paraproc","aionnae","uhiwi","mufflermankr","valorium","knighterrantry","soulune","relizex3","vinlockz","trevyn201","tiger529","xkegi","logsnsticks","meowform","uzuk3","kalzard01","squall_m","suyji","headpcgamer","sariett_siel");
$callAPI = implode(",",$username);
$data = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=' . $callAPI), true);


foreach ($data['streams'] as $streams){
$name       = $streams['channel']['name']; 
echo $name.'<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: it looks like you want to do a `foreach` of `$username` and within that foreach check `$data` to see if the user is online, instead of doing a `foreach` of `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem, if you just use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), you can filter out the usernames.

```
$online = array();
foreach ($data['streams'] as $streams)
    $online[] = $streams['channel']['name'];

$offline = array_diff($username, $online);

echo 'Online users: ' . implode(', ', $online) . "\n<br>";
echo 'Offline users: '. implode(', ', $offline);
```

Output (at time of writing):

```
Online users: sariett_siel, mufflermankr 
Offline users: zeromi, aerosgw, krylen, tshirt_aion, snooky_aion, vashiro, papa456, vinley_aion, hanfkrokette, wtfast_siel, neckofthewood, paraproc, aionnae, uhiwi, valorium, knighterrantry, soulune, relizex3, vinlockz, trevyn201, tiger529, xkegi, logsnsticks, meowform, uzuk3, kalzard01, squall_m, suyji, headpcgamer
```

Comment: Thank you. PHP is not my cup of tea as I'm sure it's obvious.